# How to use a style several times in a resourcedictionary from an external resourcedictionary?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary

I have a style for button inside a resourcedictionary, and now I want to use this style in another resource several times(for several buttons), but it just effects on the last button.
What's the problem here?

Edit:
this is my style:(CommonControlStyles.xaml)

```
 <ResourceDictionary .....>
 .
 .
 .
 <Style  TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="ListButtonsStyle">
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="35"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="Images\up.png"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
.
.
.
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and now i want to use this style in another resource dictionary(myResourcedictionary.Xaml)

```
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/...StyleResource;component/CommonControlStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

 <Button  x:Name="btn1"  Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource ListButtonsStyle}"/>
 <Button  x:Name="btn2"  Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource ListButtonsStyle}"/>
 <Button  x:Name="btn3" Grid.Column="0" Style="{DynamicResource ListButtonsStyle}"/>
```

but it just effects on btn3!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't `DynamicResource` it should be `StaticResource`.

You should use `DynamicResource` for changeable resources (for example: system colors). But your style is constant and `StaticResource` should be your choice.

Comment: Could you send link to you zipped project? I can't image how it can don't work.