# Using a style from a MergedDictionary multiple times

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, resourcedictionary

I have the very same question as posted a year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258207/how-to-use-a-style-several-times-in-a-resourcedictionary-from-an-external-resour), however the supposedly correct answer does not work at all, as stated in a comment over there.

My setup is similar to the one described in the original question: I Have one resource dictionary which contains two BitmapImages and one Style to be applied to a PushButton which selects one of these images based on a trigger on the IsChecked property.

A second resource dictionary (e.g. a separate xaml file containing one resource dictionary) adds the first resource dictionary (e.g. the first xaml file) through a MergedDictionary and then applies this style to *multiple* PushButtons. But for some reason I cannot fathom, the style is only applied to *one* PushButton at a time. Toggling a different PushButton then applies the style to the newly toggled PushButton and removes it from the previous PushButton.

This behavior is clearly not the intended one. I would love to post the xaml code, however it does not show up in the preview, even though I indented it just like any other code. Is there something special I need to do in order to post xml?

Here are two screenshots, showing what is going wrong. At first, neither of the two marked PushButtons has the style applied, even though I specified as much in the xaml file (Style={StaticResource name}).

[image: Exhibit A: Toggling the first button somehow applies the style to it]
[image: Exhibit A: Toggling the second button somehow applies the style to that one but removes the style from the first button]

To clarify, I *never* wrote any xaml code to apply different styles based on whether the PushButton is toggled or not. Both PushButtons in this image use the very same style (bound as a StaticResource), but WPF doesn't seem to care about it.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say without seeing your XAML, but this is almost certainly down to your visual tree. That is, WPF is creating one instance (singleton) of your styles and is therefore only able to host any visuals within in one place. Therefore, the last control to have that style applied "wins" and takes ownership of that visual tree.

To test my theory, you could try setting `x:Shared="False"` on your XAML resources. However, to suggest a proper fix, I'd need to see your XAML.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How do I post xaml code though? It doesn't show up in the preview when I try to add it.

Comment: Make sure it's indented correctly. Read the help near the edit control for details on markdown.

Comment: Thanks for your help. x:Shared="False" was indeed the culprit.

Comment: @Simon: technically, you're just circumventing the real problem. Chances are, you could refactor your resources so that they can be shared, thus yielding better performance. But, like I said, I can't provide guidance on that unless I see the actual XAML (or an analog repro of your scenario).

Comment: Thanks for your continued suggestions. I will be able to post my code once I'm at work again (so probably around next thursday). I would be happy if you can spare some time to help me implement a proper solution then.